# How to find hidden keybinding to maximize windows in Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

Upon configuring my keyboard shortcuts for my gnome desktop, I discovered that I cannot get rid of a hidden keyboard shortcut for maximizing the focused window with <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd>. I am using GNOME Shell 3.24.2 on Ubuntu 17.04.

If I open the keyboard shortcuts in the settings it shows that the shortcut is set to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd>, and this shortcut is active too.

I have similar issues with all the other `resize-window` key-bindings. Any idea how I can fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open **dconf Editor** and navigate to `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/`. You'll find it there.